# How to remove the line break at the end of a string?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

How do I remove a line break at the end of a string? I can use RegEx or string.indexOf().

What I have so far doesn't work:

```js
var message = "first paragraph.\n\nNext paragraph.\n";
var trimMessage = message.lastIndexOf("\n")==0 ? message.substring(0, message.length-2) : message;
```

Comment: Why would you use `==0` for the **end** of a string?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Regex to the rescue:

```
var trimMessage = message.replace(/\n$/, '');
```

The `$` means "end of input."

Example:

```js
var message = "first paragraph.\n\nNext paragraph.\n";
var trimMessage = message.replace(/\n$/, '');
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerHTML =
  "Message:\n***" + message + "**\n\ntrimMessage = ***\n" + trimMessage + "***";
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Your use of `-2` in your example makes me think you may be dealing with `\r\n` linebreaks, or possibly sometimes `\n` and sometimes `\r\n`. Or if you're going back in time, just `\r` (old Mac OS, before the BSD fork). To handle **all** of those, you can use a character class and `+` meaning "one or more":

```
var trimMessage = message.replace(/[\r\n]+$/, '');
```

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add I have line breaks in the middle of the text. I've updated the post with the new data. Will try this in the mean time.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts: That's fine, the above will leave those linebreaks alone. `/\n$/` means "a single linebreak at the end of the input."

Comment: Regex is nice but it's not very readable or self explanatory, and can get you into trouble easily, especially if you're just copy-pasting other people's patterns.

Comment: @JCD: If you've been doing JS for any length of time, you're not going to have **any** trouble reading `/\n$/` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

I like regular expressions myself:

```
var t = message.replace(/[\r|\n|\r\n]$/, '');
```

In this case, it catches all three forms of a EOL, something I do out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Javascript solution.

Your code is testing if the newline is at the **beginning** of the string, not the end.

```
var trimMessage = message.length && message.charAt(message.length-1) == "\n" ? message.slice(0, -1) : message;
```

The `message.length` test at the beginning prevents trying to access a negative position if the string is empty.

Comment: Could you use  `message.charAt(message.length-1)` instead?

Comment: FYI In ActionScript3 this `message[message.length-1]` throws an error but charAt() works fine. AS3 and JS are almost identical besides a few instances like this. That's ok it was for just for JS. I didn't specify on purpose.

Comment: I meant to say that my answer was only for Javascript (I lost that during some editing). I don't know AS3.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is nice, but it's tough to wrangle and you can do the same thing with simpler JS.

If you KNOW there is a newline at the end of the string:

```
var foo = "hello, world\n";
var bar = foo.substring(0, foo.length-1);
```

Or just use indexOf:

```
var foo = "hello, world\n";
var bar = (foo.indexOf("\n") != -1) ? foo.substring(0, foo.indexOf("\n")) : foo;
```

Comment: Regex **is** plain JS.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if it will have always have a line break.

Comment: @TJ true but it's very difficult to properly understand. You also can't really glance at it and easily know what it's doing (without proper comments). It can also have some crazy unintended consequences, especially if you're just copy-pasting regex that other people have posted. Sometimes readability, maintainability, and understandability trump fancy regex.

Comment: @JCD: Oh, I think if you've been doing JS for any length of time, you can glance at `/\n$/` and know exactly what it does. :-)

Comment: @TJ if he were at that point he wouldn't have had to ask, right? My point is that cargo-culting regex is highly dangerous. At least qualify it with "get comfortable with regex so you know what's going on."

Comment: In the first example this works but I may have previous line breaks before this one. In those cases it trims the string too early.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.
You can add a ternary operator to check if it is the last line or not.

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    result +=`${table} x ${i} = ${table * i} ${i === 10? "":"\n" }`;
}
```